# Intraweb 14.1.5 TIWTabControl and TIWfileuploader component not working in IE browser

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, intraweb

I am using intraweb 14.1.5 version in delphi XE5, Using TIWTabControl in web page but while running web page in IE browser page is getting stuck also getting issue while using TIWFileUploader file is not uploading when running through IE browser. 
Both component work properly if I run same web application in Mozilla or Chrome.
so is there any property of them need to set ?

Comment: In previous intraweb version-10 both components are working properly in IE browser but getting issue while using intraweb 14.1.1

Comment: There was an incompatibility with older IE 7/8 and IW 14.1.5 which was fixed in 14.1.6 (about TIWTabControl). TIWFileUploader works with all browsers. IE 7+ is supported. Have you downloaded and tested an IWFileUploader demo to check that? https://iwdemos.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Atozed Demos/XIV/Delphi/FileUploader/

Comment: Ok, Thank you alexandre. I will update intraweb and check for same

Comment: Thank you alexandre, both component are working properly in IE.

Comment: there one more issue i am facing with TTIWdbAdvWebGrid component, In grid if i am selecting a row then page is reloading but again i am selecting same row then also page is reloading, in previous intraweb (10.x) for same row selecting again and again page is not reloading. I don't know where is actual issue ? Is there any property for this? Please help..

Comment: I'm not sure about this, because this control is a TMS one, not default IntraWeb component. I don't have it so I cannot answer this.

Comment: Ok, Thank you for help. Tabcontroler and FileUploader issue is solved.

Comment: Hi..I am facing one more issue, If I set servercontroller.AllowMultipleSessionPerUser is true then session id is displaying in URL. In previous version there was session tracking property but in new version is there any property to hide sessionId from URL ?I want to hide session id from URL. Also i want to restrict same session to open from same browser, for this also is there any property ?

Please Help..

Comment: AllowMultipleSessionPerUser should be set to FALSE if you don't want it to appear in the URL. You only can restrict it to open from some browser if you use OnBrowserCheck event (Check ServerController). You can just terminate the session there, depending on the browser UA string.

Comment: But i want multiple Session in single browser and i want to restrict second user from taking first user's session. So is there any property to hide session Id from url instead of setting allowmultipleSessionPerUser is false. In previous version of intraweb 10, I was using property, sessiontrackingmethod =tmhidden  to solved problem as discussed above. This session tracking property is not getting in new version. please suggest any solution..

Comment: What do you mean by "second user from taking first user's session"? This is only possible if the URL is known in advance by the second user. I believe that the second user in your example is in another machine?

Comment: No,using same machine but taking its remote by multiple person. So here second person can easily known url because in IE addressbar its displaying. So I want such a solution which hide session id and $ sign from URL, and also getting different session while its using app url in multiple tab of same browser. In previous intraweb version all this issue handled by sessiontrackingmethod property but in new version I am not getting any property to related this

Comment: I just want to hide **sessionID** and and **$** from url while using **MultipleSessionPerUser = true** , so please help for this issue